# Using LINQ to compare a searchstring with the value of all the string properities of a EF class

Tags: linq, search, properties, iteration

In my ASP.NET application I have an EF `Product` class (derived from **Product** DB table) and I want to perform search functionality on its **string** fields by using inline LINQ.

Since I predict the name and amount of the fields (properties) **will change** I do not want to strongly couple my code with the table definition. How can I compare the values of all the fields in the table with a search string by **iterating** through all table fields (properties)?

I know one option is through **reflection**, is there any easier and more immediate way to fulfill this task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search on all fields of an entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844779/search-on-all-fields-of-an-entity)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, your EF class is still just a normal .NET class. Unless EF explicitly provides some library for looping through properties (it doesn't that I know of), you'll still need to use reflection to do this.

```
var properties = typeof(Product).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (var property in properties) 
{
    ...
}
```