# Search on all fields of an entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, properties, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to implement an "omnibox"-type search over a customer database where a single query should attempt to match any properties of a customer.

Here's some sample data to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
FirstName  | LastName  | PhoneNumber | ZipCode | ...
--------------------------------------------------
Mary       | Jane      | 12345       | 98765   | ...
Jane       | Fonda     | 54321       | 66666   | ...
Billy      | Kid       | 23455       | 12345   | ...
```

- If the query was `"Jane"`, I'd expect row #1 to be returned as well as row #2.
- A query for `12345` would yield rows #1 and #3.

Right now, my code looks pretty much like this:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> searchResult = context.Customer.Where(
    c => c.FirstName   == query ||
         c.LastName    == query ||
         c.PhoneNumber == query ||
         c.ZipCode     == query
         // and so forth. Fugly, huh?
);
```

This obviously works. It smells like really bad practice to me, though, since any change in the Entity (removal of properties, introduction of new properties) would break stuff.

So: is there some LINQ-foo that will search across all properties of whatever Entity I throw at it?

Comment: Couldn't you do it using reflection?

Comment: @IronMan84 How would I go about that? Just starting out with c# and .net stuff ...

Comment: isn't that one of the nice things to have? If you remove a property, you'll get compile error.

Comment: @AD.Net But he might also want it to flexible to the point where he could add more properties and it would still work just the same. Hence, why I mentioned reflection.

Comment: @AD.Net I guess that depends on the way you look at it. I'd rather not have to rewrite all of my queries every time a property is added to an entity or removed from one. Also, **people tend to forget about stuff**; a property *added* to the entity but not to the query won't throw a compiler error. The compiler won't do the bughunting for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

first find all properties within Customer class with same type as query:

```
var stringProperties = typeof(Customer).GetProperties().Where(prop =>
    prop.PropertyType == query.GetType());
```

then find all customers from context that has at least one property with value equal to query:

```
context.Customer.Where(customer => 
    stringProperties.Any(prop =>
        prop.GetValue(customer, null) == query));
```

Comment: Except that not all of his properties are strings, like PhoneNumber or ZipCode.

Comment: you mean type of 'query' is not string but object?

Comment: It would almost have to be, wouldn't it?

Comment: Brilliant solution! FYI, `query` is actually a string since I'm dealing with the `WebApi`. Therefor, I ended up iterating over all properties (not only strings) and calling `.ToString()` on them (obviously catching `null` values in the process). The `.Any` part now looks like this: `.Any(prop => ((prop.GetValue(customer, null) == null) ? "" : prop.GetValue(customer, null).ToString().ToLower()) == query)`

Comment: It can search correctly but it takes a lot time. Just for 872 records of a class having 15 properties it takes 6 minutes..... is there any other solution for this? Thnx.

Comment: I know it's not an optimal search, in your case I suggest the straight-forward methods like having long stored procedures for large tables addressing columns separately. or writing 15 consequent search statements reading from the same context.

Comment: Just had a similar case: It turned out that executing the SQL directly is efficient and fast.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working on .Net 6  with EFcore6 I keep getting an error of `System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Object' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo'..`

Comment: @Isu are you sure you wrote it correctly? I don't think .net 6 has such a huge backward incompatibility in it. Try not to just copy-paste and make sure you've understood the code properly.

Comment: @Bizhan I obviously changed the code, after looking the error up I think it has to do with EFCore 6. Meanwhile I used another alternative to solve this same problem, which is using [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) that lets you dynamically build predicates and offers an `Or` operator.

Comment: @Isu Fair point, the code works for ef4 and ef6 alike. But if you know what the problem was with your ef6 code feel free to add your own answer.